# Using pipes write input to cat command

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am new to using pipes and forking in general. What I want to do is create a program that will execute the "cat" function in bash indirectly such that I can send input to cat through my program and receive the output in a text file.

I am having two problems:

Using the execvp function, is there a way of running "cat" without being forced to interact with the prompts, and instead send input through C?

The other issue is catching the input from the cat and writing it to a text file.

For instance, if I wrote something like

```
send_cat("hi");
send_cat("hello");
```

Then in the text file it would read

```
hi
hello
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far (see: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Also, what do you mean by *"without being forced to interact with the prompts"* with regards to `cat`?

Comment: "*is there a way*". Yes, this is a very standard thing to do. Use `dup` to redirect the stdin and stdout of the child process (the one that runs `cat`).

Comment: How would your process know which text file to write to?  Or would it be shell redirection that writes to the file?  Note that something is going to have to add the newlines separating the separate outputs — `cat` won't do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem you're describing involves the use of the [pipe()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pipe-system-call/) system call and the [dup2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dup-dup2-linux-system-call/) system call.

Basically, you'd set up a `pipe()` between the parent and child processes, and then your solution should use `dup2` to redirect the stdin of the child process that runs `cat` to come from the stdin of the process that calls `execvp`. Your solution should do something similar for stdout: use `dup2` to redirect the stdout of the `execvp` child process to the stdout of the program.

**Edit:** There was a bit of hand-waving done in the above explanation, and you caught me in an extremely generous mood, so such a program structure might look like this:

**Edit 2**: I first tried writing this example program with `cat` instead of `echo`, but then I realized that you'd need to somehow send an EOF signal to the `cat` process from within the `cat` process, and sending a `'\0'` is ineffective.

```
    int pipefd[2];

    int result = pipe(pipefd);

    if (result < 0) {
        // pipe error
        perror("pipe failure");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Redirect the program's stdout and stdin to go to and from the pipe, respectively.
    // This means that "echo"'s output will go to the pipe, and when "echo" finishes and we return execution to the parent process, we'll be able to read the information that "echo" just output from that pipe

    // This is necessary in order to restore stdin and stdout to what they were prior to running this program
    int savedStdin = dup(0);
    int savedStdout = dup(1);

    // Redirect stdin to come from the pipe
    if ( dup2(pipefd[0], 0) < 0 ) {
        perror("dup2 error");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Close the read end of the pipe because the original descriptor was dupliechoed
    close(pipefd[0]);

    // Redirect stdout to go to the pipe
    if ( dup2(pipefd[1], 1) < 0 ) {
        perror("dup2 error");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Close the write end of the pipe because the original descriptor was dupliechoed
    close(pipefd[1]);

    if ( fork() == 0 ) {


        // Child process, will call "echo" and die
        execlp("echo", "echo", "Hello_world!", NULL);

        // The program should never ever get to this point, ever
        // but if it does, we need to handle it
        exit(1);
    } else {

        // Parent process, we need to wait for "echo" to terminate

        wait(NULL);

        // At this point stdout and stdin are still coming to/from the pipe, so if we do something like cin >> s, that will read from the pipe

        // First, let's restore stdout to what it was before we redirected it, so that we can print the output of "echo" to the terminal
        if (dup2(savedStdout, 1) < 0 ) {
            perror("dup2 error");
            exit(1);
        }

        close(savedStdout);

        string s;
        // Now we're going to read from stdin (the pipe) and print to stdout (the terminal, if you're running this from the command-line)
        while (cin >> s) printf("%s\n", s.c_str() );

        // We've read everything from "echo", let's fix stdin now

        if (dup2(savedStdin, 0) < 0 ) {
            perror("dup2 error");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(savedStdin);
    }
```